# Windows 7 encrypting downloaded files

Tags: windows-7, encryption

For some reason, I have several Windows 7 installs which are encrypting files that have been downloaded from another location (I have seen this behaviour through both IE, Firefox and Outlook) - the file names are green, and on checking their properties they all have the option to encrypt files selected.

Any thoughts?

Regards
Moo

Answer (score 1):

If the folder you are downloading them to has NTFS encryption enabled, then any files saved to that folder will be encrypted.

NTFS encryption is not enabled by default for any folders, so it must've been turned on manually.

Are these machines members of an Active Directory domain, or just standalone, i.e. in a workgroup?

Comment: All of them are standalone, and none of them have had encryption turned on manually.  Its interesting to note that it seems to be zip files which have been unzipped by Windows which are having the issue.